# Vue JS Nested Lists: Pass Props to Child, and to Child of Child

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create nested lists 3 levels deep with Vue.js 2.x. I'm passing props from the outer list to the middle list and from there to the inner list.

However, only the outer list renders. No errors are thrown. The inner lists seem not to receive any data.

### Fiddle of my code  [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/estabahn/c70w1k68/4/)

### Markup

```
 <div id="app">
  <ul>
    <outer-item v-for="item in items" v-bind:item="item">
      <ul>
        <mid-item v-for="mid in item.mids" v-bind:mid="mid">
          <ul>
            <inside-item v-for="inside in mid.insides" 
               v-bind:inside="inside"></inside-item>
          </ul>
        </mid-item>
      </ul>
    </outer-item>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
 Vue.component('outer-item', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '<li>{{item.text}}</li>'
})
Vue.component('mid-item', {
  props: ['mid'],
  template: '<li>{{mid.text}}</li>'
})
Vue.component('inside-item', {
  props: ['inside'],
  template: '<li>{{inside.text}}</li>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [{
          text: 'Outer A',
          mids: [{
            text: 'Mid A',
            insides: [{
              text: 'Inside A'
            }, {
              text: 'Inside B'
            }]
          }, {
            text: 'Mid B',
            insides: [{
              text: 'Inside C'
            }, {
              text: 'Inside D'
            }]
          }]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite simple: You have components which all have `li`s as templates. Now you're trying to bind other components into these `li`s - that doesn't make sense I think. :)

The fix: Change the templates to use [Vue's `<slot></slot>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) and add the text output:

```
// Do this for all other components
Vue.component('outer-item', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '<div><li>{{item.text}}</li><slot></slot></div>'
})
```

Comment: This works. I didn't add the div element you show in your solution. Updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/estabahn/c70w1k68/12/